# Is it possible to have android contacts with only a carddav sync

Tags: sync, google-contacts

I use android contacts and have my contacts synced with carddav. at the moment I have a google account in which new contacts seem to go. I try to get away from using google.

Can I drop the google account?

Will new contacts then be stored in the carddav list, which will be synced.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can disable contact sync in Google settings or use a phone without Google account.